# ArcGIS LicenseManager for Linux Installer cannot run in this UI mode

Tags: ubuntu, arcgis-license-manager

I think the issue is with 32-bit packages that are missing, but I can't figure out which ones.

I'm trying to install ArcGIS Licence Manager (which came with ArcGIS 10.8.1 for Linux) on Ubuntu 20.04. When I run the setup I get:

```
~/Downloads/LicenseManager_Linux$ ./Setup
WARNING: This setup may need additional 32-bit compatibility libraries on a 64-bit OS.

Starting installation of ArcGIS License Manager 2020.0...

Graphical installers are not supported by the VM. The console mode will be used instead...


=======================================================

Installer User Interface Mode Not Supported

The installer cannot run in this UI mode. To specify the interface mode, use the -i command-line option, followed by the UI mode identifier. The valid UI modes identifiers are GUI, Console, and Silent.

=======================================================

Note: For information on the silent setup UI mode, please run this script with the -h or --help option.

Preparing to install...
Extracting the JRE from the installer archive...
Unpacking the JRE...
Extracting the installation resources from the installer archive...
Configuring the installer for this system's environment...

Launching installer...
```

That's all that happens. Nothing launches. I've googled around and searched here for solutions, which is why I think it's a 32-bit packages thing, but I'm not sure.

Would anyone have any ideas?

Comment: All the packages listed here https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/latest/os-limits-linux.htm is probably overkill, but determining the minimum subset would be a major pain.

Comment: Thank you Vince, much appreciated.